# DelcarationError: Undeclared identifier on token creation

Tags: solidity, tokens, error

getting this error, any assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
browser/ballot.sol:166:17: DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
      require(_to != address(0));
              ^-^



function mintToken(address _target, uint256 _mintedAmount) onlyAdmin supplyLock public {
    require(_to != address(0));
    balances[_target] = SafeMath.add(balances[_target], _mintedAmount);
    totalSupply = SafeMath.add(totalSupply, _mintedAmount);
    Transfer(0, this, _mintedAmount);
    Transfer(this, _target, _mintedAmount);
}
```

Comment: Where is `_to` defined? Maybe you meant to write `_target`?

Comment: _target works great.. tyvm

Answer (score 1):

you have to first declare the `_to` variable before using it. The error name says it all.

> DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.

In your code there's nothing declared before as `_to`, to compare with `address(0)` at `require(_to != address(0));`.

You may have to include it in function parameters as `function mintToken(address _target, address _to, uint256 _mintedAmount)` or first declare it as `address _to = <some address goes here>`.

Or else here `require(_to != address(0));`,  `_to` should be something else. Possibly `_target` as suggested by @smarx in comments.

Comment: @MorganChan it's better if you can an accept answer, it might help other users as well